# Tweet button shows incorrect of tweets

Tags: javascript, html, button, twitter

On a page I have a Tweet button, like this:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-count="horizontal" data-text="#{tw_listing(@data)}", data-url="false">Tweet</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

The problem is that in the bubble with counts of tweets is the value **2197**, which is incorrect.
How to put there the correct value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're specifying:

```html
<a ... data-url="false" .../>
```

Twitter reads this value as the URL you're wanting to share, and is ultimately under the impression that the URL "false" has been shared 2,197 times. If you want to share a static URL, this attribute must relate to the URL of the page you're wanting users to Tweet about. If your page was http://example.com, for instance, you'd use:

```html
<a ... data-url="http://example.com" .../>
```

(Which has been shared [1,492 times](http://jsfiddle.net/haZy2/)).

If you want to share the URL of the page the button is added to, you'd simply remove the `data-url` parameter altogether:

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/share"
   class="twitter-share-button"
   data-lang="en"
   data-count="horizontal"
   data-text="#{tw_listing(@data)}">Tweet</a>
```

If you need help with creating your Tweet button, you should refer to the official creation page at [twitter.com/about/resources/buttons](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons).